# Nokogiri: How to allow only the Facebook Pixel in the input and remove all HTML and scripts?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, nokogiri

I have a system which the users can put some codes in the HTML. For security reasons, we don't allow to put the `<script>` tag.

Example, to insert the Google Analytics, we get the user `UA-CODE` and our system generates the Google Analytics Script.

But to insert the Facebook Pixel is a little bit more complicated, because this software has many custom options, and the final code is always different.

There's a way to get only the Facebook Pixel script in an input?

The code is like that:

```
<!-- Facebook Pixel Code -->
<script>
!function(f,b,e,v,n,t,s)
{if(f.fbq)return;n=f.fbq=function(){n.callMethod?
n.callMethod.apply(n,arguments):n.queue.push(arguments)};
if(!f._fbq)f._fbq=n;n.push=n;n.loaded=!0;n.version='2.0';
n.queue=[];t=b.createElement(e);t.async=!0;
t.src=v;s=b.getElementsByTagName(e)[0];
s.parentNode.insertBefore(t,s)}(window, document,'script',
'https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/fbevents.js');
fbq('init', 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX');
fbq('track', 'PageView');
</script>
<noscript><img height="1" width="1" style="display:none"
src="https://www.facebook.com/tr?id=1026290407456147&ev=PageView&noscript=1"
/></noscript>
<!-- End Facebook Pixel Code -->
```

If the user to put some extra scripts in this input field, I'd like to remove.

```
ruby -v: ruby 2.2.2p95
rails -v: Rails 4.2.1
nokogiri -v: Nokogiri (1.8.0)
```

Comment: Why not just ask the user to submit the various options, then generate this code on the server??

Comment: For example, [this](https://github.com/railslove/rack-tracker#facebook) was the first result from a quick google search; could that solve your problem?

Comment: Hello @TomLord, thanks your answer. I would not like to our system generate the code, because Facebook is always changing and always adding new features. But I know to filter the code with Nokogiri, maybe will be not possible... We'll thinking about your answer. Thanks man!

Comment: It's really not practical to inspect the contents of arbitrary `<script>` tags; *especially* when "features are always being added". My recommendation, as I say, would be to have the server generate the code. If facebook adds a new feature, you update the server code (e.g. the gem version) to support it.

Comment: You are right @TomLord, we will use your solution. Can you post an answer? Then I'll accepet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's really not practical to inspect the contents of arbitrary `<script>` tags; especially when "features are always being added" (so you don't even have well-defined acceptance criteria).

My recommendation would be to have the server generate the code. If Facebook adds a new feature, you update the server code (e.g. the gem version) to support it.

[This library](https://github.com/railslove/rack-tracker#facebook), for example, provides server-side generation of the Facebook pixel, given a hash of options.

Comment: We are implementing this solution, but the unique problem is: The PIXEL_ID is dynamic. The users can put their own Facebook Pixel Code. But, in this gem, the Facebook Pixel Code is unique for all the system. In the config, we need to put the PIXEL_ID, but the system knows what is the pixel id in controller, when page loads. We are trying to change the code to put the pixel_id in the controller, but at the momento, without success. Do you know how to make it dynamic?

Comment: Look at the source code -- Under the hood, that library is using [this template file](https://github.com/railslove/rack-tracker/blob/05265a3273944215f58992f34e9ad9dcb08ee5fc/lib/rack/tracker/facebook/template/facebook.erb) to generate the script, given  bunch of options. You don't necessarily need to use that gem; it was, as I said, just the first result of my google search. Maybe there's a more suitable gem, or you could quite easily roll your own custom solution with that template as a guideline.

Comment: Before you reply I was looking for [this template](https://github.com/railslove/rack-tracker/blob/master/lib/rack/tracker/facebook_pixel/template/facebook_pixel.erb) trying to found a solution. But is not clear at the moment. I'll keep study a little bit more, but if you have some tip to me, I'll appreciate a lot.

Comment: There's a [change in progress](https://github.com/railslove/rack-tracker/pull/101) to allow the PIXEL_ID dynamic. Almost done as I see. I'll put the Facebook Script directly in the template and, when the change is finished, I'll change. Thanks for all your answers @TomLord

Comment: If such a gem doesn't exist already, perhaps you could even package your mini library up as one, for others to use!